# bencode и его особенности

Tags: c++, шифрование, протоколы, torrent

Прочитал протокол от корки до корки несколько раз но так и не смог понять , почему некоторые спецификаторов формата дублируются,например 'll' вместо 'l', в спецификации ни слова про дублирования. Может кто то даст ссылку или вкратце обьяснит с чем связанно. Так же иногда дублируется символ конца 'e' и выглядит так 'ee'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим, как должно в таком кодировании выглядеть число 10. Это будет `i10e`.

Как кодируется массив? `l<содержимое>e`.

А как же будет выглядеть массив на 2 элемента 1 и 2? (то есть, массив `[1,2]`)? Это будет так  `l i1e i2e e` (пробелы добавлены для читаемости). Вот и получается в конце две буквы e. Но одна - это конец записи числа, а вторая - конец списка.

А теперь сложнее. А как будет выглядеть список(массив), внутри которого находится вышеуказанный массив? `l l i1e i2e e e` (пробелы снова для читаемости). Да у нас тут две l и три(!!!) e

Еще раз, если это не очевидно, в виде дерева (# - это начало комментария)

```
l       # [
  l     #   [
    i1e #     1,
    i2e #     2
  e     #   ]
e       # ]
```